# How to smooth/bend a specific edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I am a beginner, I tried with basic tutorials, but I can't actually solve this.

If I have this:
[image]

How can I get this following shape?
[image]

In other words, what I would like to do is to get the same shape as where the hams are hung. Thanks! (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Bevel

Easiest way for your particular case is probably to use the *Bevel* operator (other softwares sometime call this operation *Charmfer*) you can find in the Edge section of the Mesh sub-menu.

Other possible ways could be to use SubSurf modifier with proper crease or take advantage of capped&extruded curves, but for the example you bring in, these kind of approaches don't look particularly helpful.

[image]

You can find an in-depth explanation of the usage the the [Blender reference manual's page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html), but basically you should:

- enter edit mode
- select the eges you would like to bevel
- run the command from the menu or press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- adjust the size with the mouse cursor
- increase the number of segments with the mousewheel
- click to confirm

You can change the parameters even in the panel of the toolshelf on the lower left (or in the pop up menu you can call with *F6*).